# Refresh data on change in scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, watch

I'm using AngularJS for an external web project.
I'm stuck with the update interval of the page as the JSON data I get is from the html div from inside the page, JSON data is being sent from policy.
I'm using

```
$scope.json_data = angular.element(document).find('#idofthejsondiv').html();
```

The div gets different JSON data for every 'x' seconds.

How can I update the page on the change in the divs value?

Comment: I am not sure but you can try: $scope.$watch('json_data',function(){ //code });

Comment: Can you clarify how the contents of the div are changing? Is this being done by angular or by some other framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$scope.$watch (
    function () {
        return angular.element(document).find('#idofthejsondiv').html();
    },
    function (newValue) {
        console.log (newValue);
        // do stuff with the new value...
    }
);
```

but it has to be mentioned that this doesn't seem like a appropriate structure of your app. the data in the div has to be changed somewhere somehow by some service. the better approach would be to intercept this service whenever it puts the changes to the div and do whatever you want with that new content